# Use utf-8 character for curses border

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, gnome-terminal, python-curses

I can't use `█` character for curses border with.

Code example:

```py
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
c = '█'
stdscr.border(c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c)
stdscr.getch()
```

I obtain this error:

> OverflowError: byte doesn't fit in chtype

I can however use `addstr` for write some utf-8 character like this:

```py
stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "█")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the Python `curses` package is just a wrapper over the ncurses C library. And in ncurses (https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses), a character is represented as a *chtype, (character and attribute data)* where the character is a C `char` type which is just a byte on common systems.

The underlying [`border`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/border) function expects each character of the border to be a single byte, while the 'FULL BLOCK' that you are trying to use is the unicode character  U+2588 or the UTF-8 byte string `b'\xe2\x96\x88'`. That is the reason for the error message: you try to store a 3 bytes sequence into a single byte variable.

It works fine for `addstr` because that function expects a string and accepts the 3 bytes sequence. But it would break with `addch` which expect a single string.

Said differently, the curses module will not accept multibyte UTF-8 sequences except where it expects strings.

Possible workarounds:

- the recommended way to use the underlying ncurses library and the `curses` Python module is to find a single byte encoding matching your requirements. Latin1 (ISO-8859-1) is even the default for ncurses, but other encodings could better meet your needs.
- find (or write) a Python wrapper around ncursesw. This is a variant of ncurses using wide (16 bits) characters. It would accept gladly `0x2588` as a character value, or more generally any character having a 16 bits only code point, which is just the Basic Multilingual Plane of Unicode. Unfortunately, I know none.

Comment: > find a single byte encoding matching your requirements .

 Could you please explain how to find, and use such an encoding format? I added this line: `stdscr.encoding = "utf_8"` in my program, and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @AnchithAcharya: This answer says that utf_8 is not suitable. If you use a Western European language, Latin1 (or ISO-8859-1) is fine. But you should read the Wikipedia page on [ISO-8859](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/CEI_8859) because it covers a large number of languages..

Comment: Oh my bad. The page I referred to was [this](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html), which described utf_8 as supporting all languages. I must have misunderstood it. Anyway, if it helps, I am only trying to print the block characters and box-bounding characters.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method to work with ASCII characters or utf-8 special symbols:

screen.addch(), screen.inch(): curses character has 1 byte and attribute, can be used for representation of ASCII characters and their attributes only

screen.addstr(), screen.instr(): utf-8 character = string of 3 bytes. Read as 3 byte string or print as 3 byte string followed by utf-8 decode

Examples:

```
`wchar = screen.instr(1, 1, 3)  # read 3 bytes at position y=1 and x=1`
`if wchar.decode("utf-8") == '⮞': comment = ' -> success'`
`screen.addstr(3, 1, "utf-8 symbol: " + wchar.decode("utf-8") + comment)`
```